# Return values from promise(then)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

i'm having difficulties in returning some values from a promise.

This is my code:

```
getInitialState: function() {
 var me = this;
 var promise = me.getChosenProtocols();

 return (promise.then(function(value) {
   var ChosenProtocols = Object.keys(value).map(key => value[key]);
   return ({
     showModal: (ChosenProtocols.length == 0) ? true : false,
     SelectedProtocols: ChosenProtocols,
     nmTitle: SE.t(218997)
   });
   }, function (value) {
     return({
     showModal: true,
     SelectedProtocols: [],
     nmTitle: SE.t(218997)
   });
 }));
},
```

So what is happening, getChosenProtocols returns a resolved promise, and i am trying to return values from it.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks everyone, it worked when i changed it to be like this:

```
getInitialState: function() {
    var me = this;

    return ({
            showModal: false,
            SelectedProtocols: [],
            nmTitle: SE.t(218997)
    });
},

componentWillMount: function() {
    var me = this; 
    var promise = me.getChosenProtocols();

    promise.then(function(value) {
        var selectedProtocols = Object.keys(value).map(key => value[key]);

        me.setState({
            showModal: (selectedProtocols.length == 0 ) ? true : false,
            SelectedProtocols: selectedProtocols
        })
    });
},
```

Comment: Where do you want to return the values from the promise to? Into a variable?

Comment: Yes, into SelectedProtocols, which is a state. 
I want to set the promise result as the SelectedProtocols state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have regarding the promise looks mostly correct. The issue appears to be where you want to return the values of the promise to. It looks like you want to set an initial value in a React component based on the promise. If that's the case, create a function to return the value from the promise, then set a variable equal to the output of that function. That said, doing this within `setInitialState` isn't the recommended place. `componentWillMount` or `componentDidMount` would be more appropriate.

If `me.getChosenProtocals` is returning a resolved promise, the first function you provide to `then()` will have the returned value from the promise passed to it as the variable `value`.

Something along these lines:

```
getInitialState: function() {
  return(
    SelectedProtocols: null
  )
}

componentWillMount: function() {
  const me = this; 

  me.getChosenProtocols = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(function(){
      resolve("Success!");
    }, 250);
  });

  me.getChosenProtocols.then(function(value) {
    var selectedProtocols = Object.keys(value).map(key => value[key]);
    me.setState({
      SelectedProtocols: selectedProtocols
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it did work by setting the state inside it like you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't do async operations in `getInitialState`, you can `setState` in componentWillMount or componentDidMount. Apart from this, I strongly recommend using ES6 classes.

```
getInitialState: function() {
  return {chosenProtocols: {}};
},
componentDidMount: function() {
  var protocolsPromise = this.getChosenProtocols();
  protocolsPromise.then((value) => {
    var chosenProtocols = Object.keys(value).map(key => value[key]);
    this.setState({chosenProtocols: chosenProtocols});
  })
}
```

ES6 version

```
class ComponentName extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.getChosenProtocols = this.getChosenProtocols(bind);
    this.state = {chosenProtocols: {}};
  }


  componentWillUnmount() {
    var protocolsPromise = this.getChosenProtocols();
    protocolsPromise.then((value) => {
      var chosenProtocols = Object.keys(value).map(key => value[key]);
      this.setState({chosenProtocols: chosenProtocols});
    });
  }

  getChosenProtocols() {
    // Returns a promise
  }
}
```

Comment: I will change it to componentWillMount, anyways, how can i do it?

Comment: I updated my answer, please check it. You can also check this link https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-without-es6.html

Comment: Thank you for your help, it is greatly appreciated